# unable to install ros kinetic in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, irobot-create

I am trying to install ros kinetic kame in ubuntu 16.04 , but after trying the first step setup your sources. list. 
I am getting  cannot create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list: Permission denied what to do now

Comment: We're going to need a little more detail.  Where exactly in the process of installing KK are you when you get this error? Have you checked to make sure that you have the necessary permissions/are inputting the admin password when it prompts you?

Comment: this question might be better suited for answers.ros.org

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the problem was when running this command in the terminal:

> > sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

Could it be you forgot to run it with sudo?